# SFTP login returns "Authenticated with partial success." for public key

Tags: ssh, cygwin, sftp

As a newbie to SFTP, I am trying to log in to an SFTP server via my private key using Cygwin.

But eventually I ended up with having the "Authenticated with partial success" message. Is this client or server related? Can I assume that my private key is valid?

```
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:xxxx/wwww/yyy
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
Authenticated with partial success.
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, my SFTP provider figured out that I have two-factor authentication enabled for my account.

So even my private key is correct and passes; it still requires an additional step to log in.

Comment: I had the opposite: correct password, needed to provide key. Thanks.